# Should I call open API from server or from native app?

Tags: ios

I am creating a web application which also has a native app. And I use some 3rd-party open APIs in my web app. After obtaining a token with OAuth, I can call their APIs on behalf of the users.

I created the web app first, so I implemented the Oauth and API calls on the server side. Now when I am writing the native app, I realize

- I can do auth(OAuth or SSO) and API calls in the app,
- Or I can get the token and send back to server to finish the API calls there.

Using the server to call API means I don't need to write the API calls again in obj-C. But I am wondering if there are some advantages in calling APIs from native app.

So this is a 'best pratice' question. I don't have much experience in this area. Hope someone who has been through this can shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer doing as much as possible in the backend. From a performance perspective it sometimes allows aggregating multiple requests into a simpler response to send back to the app, thereby improving performance by moving requests from wireless to wired networks.